# Upload Images to Firebase IOS

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase-realtime-database

With the new updates the current answers to this question seem obsolete. Currently I have an app where I would like to upload an image using an image picker. Please hint me towards the correct way of implementing this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please upload code so we can help guide you. Not just a general question.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, if you want to receive good answers, you'll have to put some more effort into the question. Could you give some code of things you tried and exactly what isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy to upload an image from your iOS app to Firebase.

```
let currentTimeStampInSecond = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
let imageName:String = String("\(currentTimeStampInSecond).png") // Image name
let image = ... // your UIImage

let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images").child(imageName) // Upload to /images
   if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image){
        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil
            , completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                   // success
                } else {
                   // error
                    print("errorr \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                }
                // Get the download Link
                storageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        // Handle any errors
                        print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")

                    } else {
                         let d_url = url?.absoluteString
                         print("You can download me at: \(d_url)")
                    }
                }
        })
    }
```

**My app is not uploading my images, Why?**

1. it's mostly because of your security rules. When you're in development mode. You should enable read/write from the world. But i highly advise against that in production.

> Firebase has a very nice documentation at: [Upload Files on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files)